# Get only the portion of a line that stars and ends with a custom string

Tags: ssh, sed, regular-expression, pattern-matching

I want to get only the string from Failed to ssh2 included

```
Oct 20 02:40:31 test sshd[17949]: Failed password for invalid user root from 127.0.0.1 port 37111 ssh2
```

I tried with `sed 's/.*\(^Failed.*ssh2$\).*/\1/'` but it does not work. I am not sure if the problem is the regex or the sed parameters.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you remove the `^` in your regular expression: `sed 's/.*\(Failed.*ssh2$\).*/\1/'`.

Comment: Thank you, how do i stop it at the first match, if for example other "Failed" or "ssh2" attached to the string?

Comment: Feed the file to `perl -pe 's/.*?(Failed.*?ssh2).*$/\1/'`.